# jwt.verify returns res also when token expired

Tags: javascript, jwt

I'm using JWT- 'jsonwebtoken' repository.

I want to create a token and to check when it expires, If it expired, it should return me an error. For some reason, I got the decoded (res).

To create the token I'm using:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const SECRET_KEY = 'It@y W@$ H3r3';
const options = {
    expiresIn: '5s',
};

const callback = (err, token) => {
    console.log('Token:', token);
    setTimeout(() => {
        jwt.verify(token, SECRET_KEY, (err, res) => {
            console.log('res', res);
            console.log('err', err);
        });
    }, 10000);
};

jwt.sign(options, SECRET_KEY, callback);
```

For some reason I got the decoded:

```
{ expiresIn: '5s', iat: 1543574822 }
```

I should get an error like this instead:

```
err = {
    name: 'NotBeforeError',
    message: 'jwt not active',
    date: 2018-10-04T16:10:44.000Z
  }
```

Hope someone solved this problem and can assist here...
Ty, Itay.

Answer (score 1):

**jwt.sign(payload, secretOrPrivateKey, [options, callback])**

If you want to pass the expiresIn on the payload you should use **exp** not **expiresIn**:

```
jwt.sign({
  exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 60),
  data: 'foobar'
}, 'secret');
```

If you want to use **expiresIn** you must pass it on the **options**:

```
const SECRET_KEY = 'It@y W@$ H3r3';
const options = {
    expiresIn: 5,
};

jwt.sign({}, SECRET_KEY, options, callback);
```

Got the answer from a friend named Yury.
Thanks.